# Available Objects for Apex Sharing

Tags: apex, apex-managed-sharing, apex-sharing

I was using Apex Sharing and it was working fine, but then I noticed that for some objects when I use CustomObject__Share it says 'Entity is not org-accessible'. I tried to google it, but wasn't able to find any info on why I can't access Apex Sharing Objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't share any objects where the `Org-Wide Sharing Default` for it is `Public Read/Write`. Similar to how you can't set the sharing default to that level if you already use `Apex` sharing.

From [Set Your Organization-Wide Sharing Defaults](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_sharing.htm):

> The organization-wide default settings can’t be changed from private to public for a custom object if Apex code uses the sharing entries associated with that object. For example, if Apex code retrieves the users and groups who have sharing access on a custom object Invoice__c (represented as Invoice__share in the code), you can’t change the object’s organization-wide sharing setting from private to public.

Comment: Thanks, my bad. Haven't thought that if Sharing Settings set to Public Read/Write it will result as an error. Thanks for help